# retrieve domain users send-as mail gmail settings api

Tags: gmail-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to read all domain users send-as mail using gmail settings api https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/list?authuser=1 but I'm unable to read others send-as mail. The api accepts only userid ='me'. I have service account and domain delegation enabled using the google documentation. I can read all email details using Directory API, which I'm not interested in. Could someone help me with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Users.settings.sendAs: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/list?authuser=1)

> userId string  User's email address. The special value "me" can be used to indicate the authenticated user.

Assuming you have delegation set up properly you should be able to use the other users email address.  Me is only used when you want to see the information for the currently authenticated user.

Comment: @DalmTo when I use other user email address in userid field i get delegation denied error. I have enable the delegation in service account created but don't know how to use them. when i try this user.list api i was logged in as my@domain.com. could you help me with this. Thanks

Comment: If you are getting a delegation denied error then there is a problem with your service account delegation you dont have access to that users data.  Fix that and you will be all set.

Comment: Unfoutnatly i dont have access to a gusite account anymore so i cant help you test it but here are a few links https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation

Comment: @DalmTo thanks for your help. With the admin sdk api I can read all user details. but why not with gmail api users settings. I created the service account the same way as mentioned in the link above.

Comment: Admin sdk is gsuite.   Service accounts have to be set up and preapproved in the admin section over in gsuite to give it permission to access the data.

Comment: Initialy I created service accounts using this https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority  but the link you mentioned seems different. Do you think is it possible to use for gmail api scopes provided the credentials generated from admin sdk (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation)

Comment: nr 6 just add the gmail scopes and make sure you enabled gmail in the developer console for the project

Comment: I have enabled it while creating project. Also i don't find Manage third party OAuth Client access in the Authentication section inmy admin console as mentioned in  the following link developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation . I only have Manage API client access in the Authentication section. Does both mean the same ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found out the way to delegate and impersonate user.